# Detect text selection about to happen

Tags: ios, textselection

Is there a way, in iOS, to write code that is called when the system is about to display the text selection controls on a UIWebView?

I need some of my code to be called when the user wants to select something, but before the selection is actually added to the page, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around this using delayed method calls.  The selection controls do not appear immediately, but only after you tap and hold over some text for about half a second.

Here's a rough outline of the code I used to do that:

```
//in the view controller header declare a boolean
   BOOL _confirmUserIsSelectingText;

//in onTouchBegan
   _confirmUserIsSelectingText = YES;
   [self performSelector:@selector(textSelectionWillAppear:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3f];

//in onTouchMoved
   _confirmUserIsSelectingText = NO;

//in onTouchEnded
   _confirmUserIsSelectingText = NO;

//then define textSelectionWillAppear:    
- (void)textSelectionWillAppear:(id)ignoreMe
{
  //do whatever it is you need to happen before the selection controls appear
}
```

Not the best solution, but it works in my situation.  The delay can be tweaked if textSelectionWillAppear: needs more time to run, but I would think the delay shouldn't get too close to 0.5f or the method may not actually get called before the selection box appears.